# CSS - How to move an absolutely positioned item relatively to its current position

Tags: primefaces, css-position, jqplot, pie-chart, label

I am using **[PrimeFaces' pieChart](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pieChart.jsf)**. I have `.jqplot-data-label` items that represent the data labels of the chart. They are automatically positioned absolutely and I cannot position them relatively to their current position because their position is in each case automatically given by the **[jqplot PieRenderer](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-pieRenderer-js.html)**.

If I want to position them 10 pixels under the position they are now, I do the following:

```
.jqplot-data-label { margin-top: 10px !important; }
```

but I cannot position them 10 pixels **above** the position they are now.
What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: You can use negative positioning, but I assume that's not the way you *should* be going, especially if you are using `!important` already... -- because it will be a mess to maintain.

Comment: Works nicely, thank you. I know it's messy already. I would be interested to know how this will affect maintenance.

Comment: `!important` is an override... If you have a good handle on the specificity of your selectors, you shouldn't need to override anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative positioning worked for me.

```
.jqplot-data-label { margin-top: -10px !important; }
```

It also helped to read the following article:
[The Definitive Guide to Using Negative Margins](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/)